# Anomalous Relay Chattering

Tags: relay

I used 9v/DPDT relay in my circuit. I have also used 4007 SMD Diode as flyback diode. The interesting thing is, when I run my circuit, the relay starts chattering.
If I press the top surface or relay, it stops chattering. The most interesting part is, when I take the tip of screwdriver very close to the relay, it stops chattering. Does any one know what is going on here?

Comment: Sounds like you want us to guess your whole setup? Give *details*. As many as possible. You gave the model of the diode but not the relay!?

Comment: This is almost a certainly a case of lack of power going to the relay driver. AKA your P.S. is not of adequate power. The relay draws the most on pull-in, the supply drops Voltage, releases, which allows the voltage to jump up until the relay pulls in again, etc. Thereby causing the chatter.  -Sara

Comment: DC coil with AC applied?

Comment: @SaraHeart Sometimes I don't read comments before I post answers. I also added that it may be the relay switching on the load that is causing the problem, which has been my experience.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason for the chatter is because there is a power issue with energizing the coil. This can happen in a myriad of ways:

A capacitor in parallel with the inductance of the coil can make a nice harmonic resonator.

A power supply that has too high source impedance (can't source sufficient current) can cause the coil to switch on, switching the load on, drawing down the current and then the voltage drop causes the coil to switch off. When the power supply recovers the cycles starts again.

With a wierd power scheme (bad grounding or cabling) you can get wierd effects with the coil and diode.

Whatever is causing the limit cycle, the system is probably "right on the line" between oscillating and not oscillating. Any disturbance to the relay causes more energy to be dissipated and slows the coil down to the non oscillating state.

A screwdriver will provide magnetic reluctance that will steal energy from the magnetic field or redirect it, causing a change of inductance in the relays coil.

My best guess for touching the surface of the relay is that it is causing the surface of the relay to displace and more friction needed to actuate the coil.

Check the power to the coil with a scope and make sure it's steady.

Comment: I tried checking the voltage of the relay and compared with the good working one, both are same. However, the chattering stops when I add capacitor parallel to it. I believe this could be the permanent solution but I would like to know the real reason behind chattering. I have not observed in oscilloscope yet, which I am going to do now.  I am after the real cause.

Comment: Did you check it with a DMM or an oscilloscope? If you checked it with a DMM switch it to AC mode and compare